# Serialization: Step 1 Json Parser

Tags: c++, json

As nobody has provided input, I have updated the question. (The next one is coming soon)

Coding to this interface:

```
namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Serialization
    {

class ParserInterface
{
    public:
        enum class ParserToken {Error, DocStart, DocEnd, MapStart, MapEnd, ArrayStart, ArrayEnd, Key, Value};
        std::istream&   input;
        ParserToken     pushBack;

        ParserInterface(std::istream& input)
            : input(input)
            , pushBack(ParserToken::Error)
        {}
        virtual ~ParserInterface() {}
                ParserToken     getToken();
                void            pushBackToken(ParserToken token);
        virtual ParserToken     getNextToken()          = 0;
        virtual std::string     getKey()                = 0;

        virtual void    getValue(short int&)             = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(int&)                   = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(long int&)              = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(long long int&)         = 0;

        virtual void    getValue(unsigned short int&)    = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(unsigned int&)          = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(unsigned long int&)     = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(unsigned long long int&)= 0;

        virtual void    getValue(float&)                 = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(double&)                = 0;
        virtual void    getValue(long double&)           = 0;

        virtual void    getValue(bool&)                  = 0;

        virtual void    getValue(std::string&)           = 0;
};

    }
}
```

The Json Implementation is:

#### JsonParser.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_SERIALIZATION_JSON_PARSER_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_SERIALIZATION_JSON_PARSER_H

#include "Serialize.h"
#include "JsonLexer.h"
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Serialization
    {

class JsonParser: public ParserInterface
{
    enum State          {Error, Init, OpenM, Key, Colon, ValueM, CommaM, CloseM, OpenA, ValueA, CommaA, CloseA, Done};

    JsonLexerFlexLexer  lexer;
    std::vector<State>  parrentState;
    State               currentEnd;
    State               currentState;
    bool                started;

    std::string getString();

    template<typename T>
    T scan();
    public:
        JsonParser(std::istream& stream);
        virtual ParserToken getNextToken()                      override;
        virtual std::string getKey()                            override;

        virtual void    getValue(short int& value)              override;
        virtual void    getValue(int& value)                    override;
        virtual void    getValue(long int& value)               override;
        virtual void    getValue(long long int& value)          override;

        virtual void    getValue(unsigned short int& value)     override;
        virtual void    getValue(unsigned int& value)           override;
        virtual void    getValue(unsigned long int& value)      override;
        virtual void    getValue(unsigned long long int& value) override;

        virtual void    getValue(float& value)                  override;
        virtual void    getValue(double& value)                 override;
        virtual void    getValue(long double& value)            override;

        virtual void    getValue(bool& value)                   override;

        virtual void    getValue(std::string& value)            override;
};
    }
}

#endif
```

#### JsonParser.cpp

```
#include "JsonParser.h"
#include "JsonLexemes.h"
#include "UnicodeIterator.h"
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>

// enum class ParserToken {Error, MapStart, MapEnd, ArrayStart, ArrayEnd, Key, Value};
using namespace ThorsAnvil::Serialization;
using ParserToken = ParserInterface::ParserToken;

JsonParser::JsonParser(std::istream& stream)
    : ParserInterface(stream)
    , lexer(&stream)
    , currentEnd(Done)
    , currentState(Init)
    , started(false)
{}

ParserToken JsonParser::getNextToken()
{
    /* Handle States were we are not going to read any more */
    if (!started)
    {
        started = true;
        return ParserToken::DocStart;
    }
    if (currentState == Done)
    {
        currentState = Error;
        return ParserToken::DocEnd;
    }
    if (currentState == Error)
    {
        return ParserToken::Error;
    }

    // Convert Lexer tokens into smaller range 0-12
    static std::map<int, int>   tokenIndex  =
        {0,                                     0},
        {'{',                                   1},
        {'}',                                   2},
        {'[',                                   3},
        {']',                                   4},
        {',',                                   5},
        {':',                                   6},
        {ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JSON_TRUE,      7},
        {ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JSON_FALSE,     8},
        {ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JSON_NULL,      9},
        {ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JSON_STRING,    10},
        {ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JSON_INTEGER,   11},
        {ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JSON_FLOAT,     12}
    };
    // State transition table;
    static State   stateTable[][13]   =
    {
        /* Token   ->   0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7,      8,      9,      10,     11,     12 */
        /* Error */ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* Init  */ {   Error,  OpenM,  Error,  OpenA,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* OpenM */ {   Error,  Error,  CloseM, Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Key,    Error,  Error   },
        /* Key   */ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Colon,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* Colon */ {   Error,  OpenM,  Error,  OpenA,  Error,  Error,  Error,  ValueM, ValueM, ValueM, ValueM, ValueM, ValueM  },
        /* ValueM*/ {   Error,  Error,  CloseM, Error,  Error,  CommaM, Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* CommaM*/ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Key,    Error,  Error   },
        /* CloseM*/ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* OpenA */ {   Error,  OpenM,  Error,  OpenA,  CloseA, Error,  Error,  ValueA, ValueA, ValueA, ValueA, ValueA, ValueA  },
        /* ValueA*/ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  CloseA, CommaA, Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* CommaA*/ {   Error,  OpenM,  Error,  OpenA,  Error,  Error,  Error,  ValueA, ValueA, ValueA, ValueA, ValueA, ValueA  },
        /* CloseA*/ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
        /* Done  */ {   Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error,  Error   },
    };
    // Read the next token and update the state.
    int token   = lexer.yylex();
    int index   = tokenIndex[token];

    currentState    = stateTable[currentState][index];
    switch(currentState)
    {
        // These states should be impossible to get too
        case Init:      throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser: Got into Init State");
        case Done:      throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser: Got into Done State");
        // The states that we actually want to return
        case Error:     return ParserToken::Error;
        case Key:       return ParserToken::Key;
        case ValueM:    return ParserToken::Value;
        case ValueA:    return ParserToken::Value;
        // Punctuation.
        // Parse it but it is not the actual result
        // So try and get the next token.
        case Colon:     return getNextToken();
        case CommaM:    return getNextToken();
        case CommaA:    return getNextToken();
        // We are going into a containing object.

        // Push the state we want when the containing
        // object is complete then set the state we will
        // need if we open another container.
        case OpenM:
            parrentState.push_back(currentEnd);
            currentEnd  = ValueM;
            return ParserToken::MapStart;
        case OpenA:
            parrentState.push_back(currentEnd);
            currentEnd  = ValueA;
            return ParserToken::ArrayStart;

        // We are leaving the containing object.
        // Pop the state we previously saved.
        case CloseM:
            currentEnd  = currentState    = parrentState.back();
            parrentState.pop_back();
            return ParserToken::MapEnd;
        case CloseA:
            currentEnd  = currentState    = parrentState.back();
            parrentState.pop_back();
            return ParserToken::ArrayEnd;

        // Anything else just break.
        default:
            break;
    }
    // If we hit anything else there was a serious problem in the
    // parser itself.
    throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser: Reached an Unnamed State");
};

std::string JsonParser::getString()
{
    if (lexer.YYLeng() < 2 || lexer.YYText()[0] != '"' || lexer.YYText()[lexer.YYLeng()-1] != '"')
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser: Not a String value");
    }
    // Remember to drop the quotes
    return std::string(make_UnicodeWrapperIterator(lexer.YYText() + 1),
                       make_UnicodeWrapperIterator(lexer.YYText() + lexer.YYLeng() - 1));
}

std::string JsonParser::getKey()
{
    return getString();
}

template<typename T>
inline T JsonParser::scan()
{
    char*   end;
    T value = scanValue<T>(lexer.YYText(), &end);
    if (lexer.YYText() + lexer.YYLeng() != end)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser: Not an integer");
    }
    return value;
}

void JsonParser::getValue(short& value)                         {value = scan<short>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(int& value)                           {value = scan<int>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(long& value)                          {value = scan<long>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(long long& value)                     {value = scan<long long>();}

void JsonParser::getValue(unsigned short& value)                {value = scan<unsigned short>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(unsigned int& value)                  {value = scan<unsigned int>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(unsigned long& value)                 {value = scan<unsigned long>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(unsigned long long& value)            {value = scan<unsigned long long>();}


void JsonParser::getValue(float& value)                         {value = scan<float>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(double& value)                        {value = scan<double>();}
void JsonParser::getValue(long double& value)                   {value = scan<long double>();}

void JsonParser::getValue(bool& value)
{
    if (lexer.YYLeng() == 4 && strncmp(lexer.YYText(), "true", 4) == 0)
    {
        value = true;
    }
    else if (lexer.YYLeng() == 5 && strncmp(lexer.YYText(), "false", 5) == 0)
    {
        value = false;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser: Not a bool");
    }
}

void JsonParser::getValue(std::string& value)
{
    value = getString();
}
```

Comment: The only improvement I can spot here is making the tables `tokenIndex` and `stateTable` constants.

Comment: @glampert:  Not going to any points for a comment.

Comment: It's been three years. Maybe you want to review your own code?

Answer (score 2):

As an attempt to <s>kill</s> *cure* (too bad they are still far from being homophones) zombies, let me try write something here.  Here's some suggestions:

- The indentation looks absurd to me:

  ```
  namespace ThorsAnvil
  {
      namespace Serialization
      {

  class ParserInterface
  {
      // ...
  };

      }
  }
  ```

  I would typically do

  ```
  namespace ThorsAnvil::Serialization {
      class ParserInterface {
          // ...
      };
  }
  ```

  If you really want to get rid of the indentation, you can flush the namespace declarations to the left altogether.
- There has to be a better way of writing the 17 `getValue` functions.
- Are you sure these belong in a general interface?  I don't think so.

  ```
  public:
      std::istream&   input;
      ParserToken     pushBack;
  ```
- Since `scan` is a template, you should implement it in the header.
- Is this necessary?  At least the comment should be removed.  Personally, I would remove the default branch altogether, but that's pretty much a matter of state.

  ```
  // Anything else just break.
  default:
      break;
  ```
- The tables used in the implementation should probably be `const`.

Comment: Namespace: I like my format. But I like the C++17 multiple namespace in one go better. But I'll wait until 2021 when everybody is using C++17 (to many people still on C++11).

Comment: `getValue()` compiler does not differentiate on return value!

Comment: Yes. Those look like they should be private. I'll look at moving them see if any unit tests break.

Comment: Implementing `scan()` in the source file seems more logical as all the other functions are implemented there. Since it is private it can' be used anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Yes I should remove that break (and comment). That's an arcace style from the old C where switch statements were UB unless you hit a case or a default. The standard has long since been updated (I think I will check and fix).

Comment: Yes will make all the tables const.

Comment: That `default` case is actively harmful - it prevents a warning message that can otherwise be emitted when a new state is added to the `enum` and then not mentioned in the `switch`.